# Material Components for Web toolbar with text link rather than icons

Tags: toolbar, material-components-web

If I delete the icon classes from the `a href` tags in a `mdc-toolbar__section` I get unformatted links instead of the text between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags in a matching style.

Is there a way to get the toolbar items to be text instead of icons?

This shows icons in the toolbar:

```
    <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
      <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Download" alt="Download">file_download</a>
      <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Print this page" alt="Print this page">print</a>
      <a href="#" class="material-icons mdc-toolbar__icon" aria-label="Bookmark this page" alt="Bookmark this page">bookmark</a>
    </section>
```

This shows unformatted squashed together links and causes the rest of the page to render improperly:

```
    <section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
      <a href="#" aria-label="Download" alt="Download">file_download</a>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Print this page" alt="Print this page">print</a>
      <a href="#"  aria-label="Bookmark this page" alt="Bookmark this page">bookmark</a>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a `button` instead of `an a href`.

```
<section class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-end" role="toolbar">
  <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated" id="file">file_download</button>
  <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated" id="print">print</button>
  <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated" id="bookmark">bookmark</button>
</section>
```

And then some Javascript to cause the button to redirect to the required link by adding the following event to each button:

```
onclick="location.href = 'yournewlocation';"
```

You need to use an unelevated button or select the correct theme, otherwise the text will be the same color as your toolbar.